# How to replace a letter in a specific place inside a string in python, without transforming into a list?

Tags: python, string, replace, python-3.2

I want to replace a specific location on a string but it is replacing the whole string

Relevant part of the code:

```
userInput = "i"
word = "university"
answer = "*" * len(word)

if userInput in word:
        for letter in word:
            if letter == userInput:
                location = word.find(userInput)
                answer = answer.replace(answer[location],userInput)
        print(answer)
```

Current Output:

```
iiiiiiiiii
```

Desired Output:

```
**i****i**
```

Comment: It looks like you want to replace all characters that are *not* the `userInput` with a "*".  Is that correct?

Comment: all characters are *, but I want to replace the userInput that contains in the word, like a hangman game, where you can see the letters as you guess them right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what `x.replace(a, b)` does is replace any occurrences of the value `a` in `x` with `b` so `answer.replace(answer[location], userInput)` just replaces all `*` with the value of `userInput` because `answer[location]` is `*`. In other words, it's not possible to specify the index of what you want to replace like that.

So instead of:

```
answer = answer.replace(answer[location],userInput)
```

do

```
answer = answer[:location] + userInput + answer[location + 1:]
```

**UPDATE:**

The rest of the logic was also flawed, so this will work:

```
userInput = "i"
word = "university"
answer = "*" * len(word)

for location, letter in enumerate(word):
    if letter == userInput:
        answer = answer[:location] + userInput + answer[location + 1:]
```

This also contains the suggestion to use `enumerate()` by SethMMorton, which turns out to be unavoidable :)

`enumerate('abc')` will yield `[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]`, which means you won't need to use `find` as you'll already have the location (index) of the letter available right away.

Comment: This answer would be much improved if it suggested using `enumerate` in the `for` loop to get `location` instead of using the `find` method of `word`.

Comment: In general, yes, but I think the OP is struggling with the very basics of programming/Python, so I reckoned it wouldn't be such a good idea to suggest an overhaul of his program before he undersands what `x.replace(a, b)` even means.

Comment: I'm not so sure that would be a complete overhaul... it would be modifying one line and removing another.  Besides, won't `find` only locate the first instance, so `enumerate` would be more correct in that case?  Last, watch out with assuming the gender of the OP...

Comment: ah, yes, another part of your logic is wrong... let me try to fix that; @SethMMorton: sorry, didn't pay attention.

Comment: I added an answer with `enumerate` (that that is the correct answer), but you modified yours just as I added mine so in the spirit of good form I deleted mine and am upvoting yours.